# Show that if every continuous real-valued function on $E \subset R$, $E \neq \phi$ takes a maximum value, the E is closed and bounded

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology

I think to show it's bounded I could assume its not, then come up with a function that doesn't attain a max value.

I think the map: for e in E, x -> d(x,e) should work because the distance function is continuous, but it does not attain its maximum.  Is this ok? I'm a little confused if it means attain its maximum on E or just in general

I don't know how to show that it would be closed though.  I am assuming it can be done the same way, but I can't think a function that would work

Comment: FYI, you can use \Bbb{R} for $\Bbb{R}$ and \emptyset for $\emptyset$.

Comment: To show it's upper bounded it's enough to notice that the maximum of the image of the obvious inclusion $E\to \mathbb R$ is an upper bound. For lower bounded take the map $E\to \mathbb R$ sending $e\in E$ to $-e\in \mathbb R$, then minus the upper bound of the image of this will be a lower bound for $E$.

Comment: To show its closed, let $x\in \mathbb R$ be a point which is the limit of a monotone --say increasing-- sequence in $E$. If $x\in E$ you have nothing to prove while if, looking for a contradiction $x\notin E$, then consider the map $E\to \mathcal R$ such that $f(e)=e$ if $e\leq x$, while $f(e)$ is the upper bound of $E$ otherwise. This is a continuous but not closed image of $E$ in $\mathbb R$, a contradiction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

E is bounded

As you said, the map $f:E\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x) = |x|$ is continuous, by assumption $f$ takes a maximum value $M$, then, $E\subseteq B(0,M)$, hence $E$ is bounded.

E is closed

let $x_n$ be a sequence in $E$, such that $x_n\rightarrow x$ for some $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Let $f:E\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be so that  $f(y) = -|y-x|$ (where $x$ is the limit of $x_n$), this is obviously continuous, therefore it gets a maximum (by assumption).

Clearly, for every $y\in E$ you have that $f(y)\leq 0$, moreover, $f(x_n)\rightarrow 0$, it follows that the maximum must be zero (why?), hence there exists $x_\star\in E$ so that $f(x_\star)=0$ it follows that $-|x_\star-x|=0$, hence $x=x_\star$ is an element in $E$, it follows that $E$ is closed.

Comment: How does the first part show that its bounded? Couldn't another function have a maximum higher than this one?

Comment: @VinnyChase.  It shows that E is contained within a ball from which you can prove diameter E is finite, thus bounded by definition.  Yes, the set of continuous functions on a bounded set is unbounded.  So what?

Answer (score 0):

If $E$ is unbounded then $f(x)=|x|$ is continuous on $E$ and has no maximum.

If $p\in \overline E$ \ $E$ then $f(x)=\frac {1}{|x-p|}$ is continuous on $E$ and has no maximum.